# Javascript + Drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, onclick, drupal-7

My setup: A "open video" button. A form, when user clicks handouts or videos, ajax is called to render the files with the buttons.

My question is:

When I render the page and click on "open the video", I have to click out  twice to exit. I assume it is because ModalVideo is being called twice, once when it rendered and once when the form is submitted. I was wondering if anyone has any pointers or references to drupal behaviors on forms/javascript being ran once. Thank you.

```
Drupal.behaviors.customJS = {
  attach: function(context, settings){
     // import ModalVideo from 'modal-video';
     new ModalVideo(".js-video-vimeo-btn",{channel:'vimeo'});
  }
}
```

------UPDATED SOLUTION-------

```
 Drupal.behaviors.customJS = {
  attach: function(context, settings){
     //every time the view is updated on ajax call, run only once
     $('.view-pdf-views').once(function(){
         // import ModalVideo from 'modal-video';
        new ModalVideo(".js-video-vimeo-btn",{channel:'vimeo'});
     });
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use once() plugin that is delivered to Drupal. Check [JS API Overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview)

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .on() to listen for button click you should change it to .one()

http://api.jquery.com/one/